# Finding a Particular Word in Querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I am working on ASP.net pages using C# and I want to check whether my querystring has a particular word in it or not.

For example, I want to check if my querystring has

```
-?property=7960790,498751465,...,...,...,...
-?project=7960790,3298756,.....,.....,......
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on exactly what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (Request.QueryString["property"] != null) { ...
```

Comment: Might better check for `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString ...`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Request.QueryString["property"];
```

and check against `null`.

See [Request.QueryString Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The Request.QueryString object has a variety of methods and properties you can use to check querystring keys and values.

Comment: @Jan - fair enough, not the best code sample I admit, i'll remove it.